# Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit) and packages libusb-1.0-0:i386 and libusb-1.0-0-dev:i386

Tags: apt, usb, 32-bit

I need these 2 32 bit packages installed to build toradex angstrom linux.  Both of these packages will not install with sudo apt install libusb-1.0-0:i386 and sudo apt install libusb-1.0-0-dev:i386.  They also will not install using the Ubuntu Software Center due to unmet dependencies.  Any ideas how to get these packages installed?

Comment: Is there perhaps an error message? If so, may we see it?

Comment: There are no error messages per se.  apt-get will not install either libusb 32 bit package because of other i386 packages that libusb-1.0-0 depends on and states they will not be installed.  My work around to get the correct 32 bit libraries onto my 64 bit system was to create a Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit version in a VM and copy the libraries I need to the 64 bit Ubuntu system within the /lib/i386-linux-gnu directory and create the correct symbolic links.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround to get the correct 32-bit libraries for libusb-1.0-0:i386 and libusb-1.0-0-dev:i386 onto your 64-bit system is to create a Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit guest OS in a virtual machine, copy the libraries you need to the `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/` directory in the 64-bit Ubuntu host OS, and create the correct symbolic links.